# Proxy Authorization Required while uploading large files in play 1.2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am getting Proxy Authorization Required while uploading large files in play 1.2.5.
After hitting the upload button the required action doesnt get called.However when I upload small sized files I dont get this error.What can be the reason.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with play. While you can limit the size of a request (and therefore the size of uploadable files) by setting a value for `play.netty.maxContentLength` in your `application.conf`, [by default there is no limit](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/server/PlayHandler.java#L527).

The problem is most likely caused by a proxy server that sits between you and the Play application which requires authentication above a certain request size. Ask whoever is responsible for that proxy server how to circumvent this problem (e.g. by increasing the max. request size or giving you authentication credentials for the proxy).